# How to resize the MAT DIALOG on smaller screens

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material

this is my component.html file:

```html
<div class="button">
  <button (click)="openPopUp()" mat-button class="readBtn">Buy Now</button>
</div>
```

and this is it's **.ts** File.

```js
openPopUp() {
    const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
    dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
    dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
    dialogConfig.width="60%";
    this.dialog.open(GetBuyDetailsComponent, dialogConfig);
}
```

On button click I'm opening the Mat Dialog named as **GetBuyDetails**. But this GetBuyDetails Pop-up or Mat Dialog is not responsive as it's width is always **60%**. How do I make the Mat Dialog Component responsive.

Comment: I do not really understand your question. Can you please provide more details? 

As of my understanding, and reproduction, it is responsive - which means it always has the width of 60% of the actual screen size. What would you like to achieve? Or could you provide yous css file - as I see the button has a `readBtn` class - which could be the problem, if there is some overwriting there.

Comment: @vazsonyidl 
yeah it always has a width of 60%, which in small screens looks horrible, so what i want is that on smaller screen the width goes from 60% to 80%. I want to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so as of my understanding, you have two solution.

According to the [doc](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview), you have two options - you have to decide which one is better suitable for you.

**1. Overwrite the `panelClass` of the dialog.**

This can be easily achieved and you can store your styles in your component directory, the solution is the following:

**component-style.scss**

```
        ::ng-deep .my-custom-panel {
          width: 70%;
        
    // your custom logic - this is a sketch
          @media screen and (max-width: 660px){
            width: 100%;
          }
        }
```

**.component.ts**

```
      openPopUp() {
        this.dialog.open(<your component>, {
          disableClose: true,
          autoFocus: true,
          panelClass: 'my-custom-panel'
        });
      }
```

The main problem here is that you **can not scope your styles to the component**, every `.my-custom-panel` style will be globally overwritten.

**2. Use global styles for this**

May be a bit nicer, but you have to define your overlay class in your global `styles.(s)css` where you should leave off the `::ng-deep` modifier. From that point, you can simple follow the previous logic.

I will definetely go with the second, as using `::ng-deep` without any modifier (eg `:host`) is **deprecated by Angular** and a not-so-nice solution.

Hope this helped you, comment if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

Why you don't use pixel like `dialogConfig.width="360px"`?
it's also responsive on any device width.